# Utilizando el código line.readline() me sale una repetición 2 veces de la primera linea

Tags: python, python-3.x

Utilice el código ficher.txt 'w' para guardar un archivo de texto con una escritura con f.write, pero al momento de utilizar print(line.readline()), solo me sale el texto de la primera linea y no la segunda linea separada con \n, además solo me repite 2 veces la primera linea. Aquí dejo el código:

```
f = open('fichero.txt', 'w')
f.write('fichero abierto en modo escritura\n')
f.write('por defecto se trata como un fichero de texto')
f.close()

for line in open('fichero.txt'):
    line = open('fichero.txt', 'r')
    print(line.readline())

input()
```

Y me recopila el código de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te sobra la primera linea dentro del for, y la segunda debe ser `print(line)`. La variable `line` que aparece en `for line` ya irá cambiando de valor en cada iteración, conteniendo una línea diferente cada vez. No tiene sentido que vuelvas a abrir el fichero dentro del bucle (pues cada vez que lo abras vuelve a la primera línea) y además es confuso que asignes a `line` el resultado, pues `line` ya era otra cosa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que publicas es ilógico, por lo que no vale la pena examinarlo.

La solución correcta en línea con el código original sería

```
f = open('fichero.txt', 'w')
f.write('fichero abierto en modo escritura\n')
f.write('por defecto se trata como un fichero de texto')
f.close()

f = open('fichero.txt', 'r')
print(f.readline(), end="")
print(f.readline())
f.close()
```

que produce:

```
fichero abierto en modo escritura
por defecto se trata como un fichero de texto

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Para leer el archivo tienes que proceder de manera similar a como lo grabastes: haces un `open` para abrirlo y usas el *handle* retornado para leer cada línea. Al termina, lo cierras.

**Versión Pythonica**

Si bien usar open-close es válido, Python ofrece una forma más corta, que cierra automáticamente el archivo al salir:

```
with open('fichero.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('fichero abierto en modo escritura\n')
    f.write('por defecto se trata como un fichero de texto')

with open('fichero.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(f.readline(), end="")
    print(f.readline())
```

La prefiero pues se ve mejor en que parte del código el archivo está abierto para su uso.

Por supuesto, si quieres imprimir un archivo de largo indeterminado, puedes ocupar el *handle* del archivo como un iterador:

```
with open('fichero.txt', 'r') as f:
    for linea in f:
        print(linea)
```